# How to reload <ui:include>

Tags: java, richfaces, seam2, jsf-1.2

We included a page with ui:include. And when a button is clicked we want to rerender ui:included page too. Here is parent page;

```
<h:form id="mainForm">
        <a4j:region rendered="#{dealHome.editMode}">
            <ui:include src="/createEditDeal.xhtml">
                <ui:param name="id" value="#{dealHome.instance.id}" />
            </ui:include>
        </a4j:region>
        <a4j:region rendered="#{not dealHome.editMode}">
            <ui:include src="/readDeal.xhtml">
                <ui:param name="id" value="#{dealHome.instance.id}" />
            </ui:include>
        </a4j:region>
        <s:div rendered="#{dealHome.editMode}">
            <a4j:commandButton action="#{dealHome.persist()}" value="+"
                id="btnTagAdd" reRender="mainForm" />
        </s:div>
        <s:div rendered="#{not dealHome.editMode}">
            <a4j:commandButton id="btnModeChange" value="Edit"
                action="#{dealHome.changeMode()}" reRender="mainForm" />
        </s:div>
    </h:form>
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't the code in the ui:include rerendered when you render the mainForm?

Comment: I am not sure at all, but did you try with the ui:composition tag instead? If not, you might want to give it a try.